# How to display bound data horizontally in ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I want to display images from collection in ListBox in horizontal mode with scrolling option. If I got this (without scrolling), images are displayed vertically.

```
                <ListBox x:Name="SelectedImages" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                             <Image Source="{Binding Image2}" Height="110" Width="110" />
                         </StackPanel>
                     </DataTemplate>
                 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                 </ListBox>
```

If I try this, I got blank screen.

```
                <ListBox x:Name="SelectedImages" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                     <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image2}" Height="110" Width="110" />
                             </StackPanel>
                         </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ListBox x:Name="SelectedImages"  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="{Binding Image2}" Height="110" Width="110" />
         </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This gives me blank screen too.

Comment: @petrppe do you have items inside images?

Comment: What do you mean by "items inside images"? I used the code you posted.

Comment: I had to edit fourth line like this <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="110"/> and it's working.